# Coding hex to decimal gives error - how to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to code a function for hex to dec. It gives an error. How can I fix that?

```
#hex2int funciton
def hex2int(hex):
    result = 0
    counter = 0
    x = list(hex)

    while counter < len(hex):
        if x[counter] == "a" or x[counter] == "A":
            result = result + (10 * (16 ** counter))
        elif x[counter] == "b" or x[counter] == "B":
            result = result + (11 * (16 ** counter))
        elif x[counter] == "c" or x[counter] == "C":
            result = result + (12 * (16 ** counter))
        elif x[counter] == "d" or x[counter] == "D":
            result = result + (13 * (16 ** counter))
        elif x[counter] == "e" or x[counter] == "E":
            result = result + (14 * (16 ** counter))
        elif x[counter] == "f" or x[counter] == "F":
            result = result + (15 * (16 ** counter))
        else:
            result = result + (int(x[counter])* (16 ** counter))
        counter += 1

    return result
```

Comment: And the error is ? Please edit your post and add it

Comment: There's no need to convert to a list, you can index a string the same way.

Comment: You're dealing with the number backwards.  You're multiplying the first digit by 16**0, the next digit by 16**1, etc.  It's the *right-end* of the number that's the 16**0.

Comment: I get no errors from your code. It doesn't give the correct answer, but that's because your algorithm is wrong.

Comment: The more common way to deal with numbers starting from the left is to keep a running value.  If there is another digit, multiply your running value by 16 before looking at the next digit.  If not return what you have.

Comment: You should explain the error you’re getting, but it looks like it’s coming from the fact that you need to loop backwards (right to left) through the number for the powers of 16 to be correct. Also, instead of all those `elif` statements you should use a dictionary or do something with the ascii encoding of the letters

Comment: @FrankYellin "You're multiplying the first digit by 160, the next digit by 161". I think you mean that they're multiplying the first digit by `16**0`, the next digit by `16**1`, etc .

Comment: @jjramsey.  Thanks.  I forgot to put my expressions into backquotes, and SO changed by double asterisks into bold.  I forgot to proofread afterwards.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You might already know this, but this is built into Python

```
>>> int('deadbeef', 16)
3735928559
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start from the right, One way to do it is to use negative index:

```
#hex2int funciton
def hex2int(hex):
    result = 0
    counter = 0
    x = list(hex)

    while counter < len(hex):
        ch = x[-1-counter]
        if ch == "a" or ch == "A":
            result = result + (10 * (16 ** counter))
        elif ch == "b" or ch == "B":
            result = result + (11 * (16 ** counter))
        elif ch == "c" or ch == "C":
            result = result + (12 * (16 ** counter))
        elif ch == "d" or ch == "D":
            result = result + (13 * (16 ** counter))
        elif ch == "e" or ch == "E":
            result = result + (14 * (16 ** counter))
        elif ch == "f" or ch == "F":
            result = result + (15 * (16 ** counter))
        else:
            result = result + (int(ch)* (16 ** counter))
        counter += 1

    return result
```